# React compiled component loading at runtime

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Are there examples of Webpack/React apps that utilize compiled component loading at runtime?

To elaborate, I mean having a shell of sorts and rather than having all the components bundled locally with it and instead during runtime called upon from a CDN or URL to form a single cohesive app.

Answer (score 1):

You can code-split your code with any granularity with webpack https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/ and split each component to a separate file, but unless the components are huge or whole bundle it will only add HTTP overhead and general slowness and it will not benefit from SPA. If you are not planning to have 1000 components or 3Mb large bundle, just don't do it.